# Vue.js 3 - Why is importing vue-router not working in this case?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I have the following files

> router.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

export const router = VueRouter({
routes: [
     {
      ...
     }
 ]
})
```

> main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)
...
import { router } from './router'
app.use(router)
...
app.mount('#app')
```

However when doing this I get the following error Uncaught `TypeError: this is undefined - vue-router.esm.js:2828` it seems to be an error inside vue-router library since the error occures at line 2828.

This happens by just trying to import vue-router without trying to use it anywhere else in the app, I also use vuex and import export/import store the same way and it works.

My guess is that I'm importing vue-router wrong because the docs don't use `{createApp}` in the example. Am I importing it wrong, or is there some other reason it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First make sure the you've installed the vue router 4 using :

```
npm install vue-router@next
```

then import `createRouter` to create router instance:

```
 import { createRouter,createWebHistory} from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
     {
      ...
     }
 ]
})
```